# ASP.NET - Automapper not working on productive IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, automapper

I'm mapping data using Automapper in my ASP.NET MVC4 Application's from my domain model onto my view model.
On my development machine with the integrated IIS this works perfectly, however when deploying it to the real IIS, suddenly my code only maps the data seemingly on arbitrary occasions.
It seems that the mapping works once after redeploying the application and sometimes after attaching the remote debugger.

My code is:

```
iPXE dbCon = new iPXE();
Models.Device bootDevice = dbCon.Devices.SingleOrDefault(d => d.serial == serial);
var imagePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Models.Image>();
imagePredicate = imagePredicate.Or(d => d.anyboot == true); // Images everyone can boot
if (bootDevice != null) // If the boot device is in the database
{
    imagePredicate = imagePredicate.Or(d => d.Devices.Any(e => e.id == bootDevice.id)); // Retrieve all images assigned to the device
}
IEnumerable<Models.Image> allowedImages = dbCon.Images.AsExpandable().Where(imagePredicate);

Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Category, Category>()
    .ForMember(x => x.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CategoryTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale) == null || // Either no translation row found
                                                      src.CategoryTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale).name != null ? // Or specific value is null
                                                      src.name : // Then use name from main table (untranslated)
                                                      src.CategoryTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale).name)) // Otherwise use translated value
    .ForMember(x => x.images, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => allowedImages.Intersect(src.Images)));
Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Image, Image>()
    .ForMember(x => x.description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImageTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale) == null ||
                                                             src.ImageTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale).description == null ? 
                                                             src.description : 
                                                             src.ImageTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale).description))
    .ForMember(x => x.code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImageTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale) == null ||
                                                      src.ImageTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale).code == null ? 
                                                      src.code : 
                                                      src.ImageTranslations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.locale == locale).code));

categories = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Models.Category>, List<Category>>(allowedImages.Select(c => c.Category1).Distinct());

public class Category
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm doing is basically getting a device from the database, getting all assigned images for the device (N:M) and then creating Automapper-Maps for categories and images that belong to the device.

The exact problem is that on the productive server, the images-Lists of the category objects stay empty, even though there is data in `allowedImages` (5 images), `bootDevice` (the device data) and `allowedImages.Select(c => c.Category1).Distinct()` (2 categories).

I'm using the same SQL server for both my machine and the server. If you need any more information, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling 'CreateMap' each time the method runs.  As I understand, you should only do this once within your application domain.  Try moving the CreateMap logic to where it gets called from Application_OnStart to see if that gives you more consistent behavior.

Also, the line:

```
.ForMember(x => x.images, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => allowedImages.Intersect(src.Images)));
```

may be troubling you.  You may need to change that to an AfterMap that calls a static method that performs the Intersect on your source & destination collections.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it exactly.
Is there any advice you could give me concerning how to replace my local variable references (like `allowedImages` and `locale`). For allowedImages you already said to use the AfterMap-method. Would you say that's generally the best way to handle mappings that are dependent on local variables or is there something else I could have a look at? I'm using the `locale` variable for example to decide on which property to map exactly (checking if something is null, if so using a, else using the checked property).

Comment: Using the local variables is going to be trickier, I think.  You probably *will* need to use AfterMap, but I am not sure what the best method is to pass your local variables so that AfterMap can access them.  I will think about that and post a follow-up comment.

Comment: You could possibly extend your source class with a 'partial class' with properties that you would set to `allowedImages` and `locale`.  AfterMap could then access and use those properties during mapping.  Or, another option is to set those values on a destination class instance that you create, and then use one of the `Map` overloads that 'fills-out' your destination class, as opposed to the overload that creates and fills-out a new instance of the class.  Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: I felt quite uneasy changing source or destination classes since the source class was an auto-generated model and my destination class belongs to the view model and I wanted to keep it as slim as possible.
I'm currently checking out the possibility to supply arguments to the Map-method, using its second parameter like `opt => { opt.Items["key"] = value; ... }` and then writing my logic based on these parameters in a custom resolver (It seems, that the Items-dictionary is only accessible from a custom resolver, not from e.g. a FromMember-call).

Comment: Ah, good info. I didn't know about Items dictionary on the extra options. Thanks for following up.